# open cv does not capture video until setting a breakpoint

Tags: opencv

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.7, on Windows server 2012 and VS2012 (Update 3), extracted from `opencv-2.4.7.2.exe` and following opencv tutorial added required path to windows and visual studio.
following code does not work after build(returns -5), but when i set a breakpoint in 
`frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);` program works. using `cvWaitKey(33);` after and before this line, also does nothing.

i use an a4tech webcam, tested it with some webcam software having no problem. also i don't any 3rd party dll's like tbb.

in visual studio output window, i get this lines:

```
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'L:\Projects\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'L:\Projects\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_imgproc247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'L:\Projects\opencv\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.16658_none_776622cb3175a40c\comctl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvfw32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avifil32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\avicap32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msacm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\version.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmmbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\bcryptprimitives.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devenum.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntmarta.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\wintrust.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msdmo.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\qcap.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\quartz.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ksproxy.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ksuser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d3d9.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vidcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Kswdmcap.ax'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mfc42.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\odbc32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\qedit.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\WinSxS    \amd64_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.9200.16518_none_726fbfe0cc22f012\GdiPlus.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\SHCore.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd64.dll'
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd64.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'test1.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\System32\igdumd64.dll'
'test1.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msyuv.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.

The thread 0x1efc has exited with code -5 (0xfffffffb).
The thread 0x1540 has exited with code -5 (0xfffffffb).
The thread 0x1160 has exited with code -5 (0xfffffffb).
The thread 0x1af8 has exited with code -5 (0xfffffffb).
The thread 0x1c84 has exited with code -5 (0xfffffffb).
```

what is the problem with this code? or my config?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

IplImage* imgTracking;
int lastX = -1;
int lastY = -1;

//This function threshold the HSV image and create a binary image
IplImage* GetThresholdedImage(IplImage* imgHSV){       
    IplImage* imgThresh=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(imgHSV),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(160,160,60), cvScalar(180,256,256), imgThresh); 
return imgThresh;
}

void trackObject(IplImage* imgThresh){
// Calculate the moments of 'imgThresh'
CvMoments *moments = (CvMoments*)malloc(sizeof(CvMoments));
cvMoments(imgThresh, moments, 1);
double moment10 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0);
double moment01 = cvGetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1);
double area = cvGetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0);

if(area>1000){
    // calculate the position of the ball
    int posX = moment10/area;
    int posY = moment01/area;        

    if(lastX>=0 && lastY>=0 && posX>=0 && posY>=0) {
        // Draw a line from the previous point to the current point
        cvLine(imgTracking, cvPoint(posX, posY), cvPoint(lastX, lastY), cvScalar(0,0,255), 4);
    }
    lastX = posX;
    lastY = posY;
}

free(moments); 
}


int main(){

CvCapture* capture =0;       
//....1....cvWaitKey(500); this does nothing
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
//Following line also tested, and nothing happened
//cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640 );
//cvSetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480 );
if(!capture){
        printf("Capture failure\n");
        return -10;
}

IplImage* frame=0;
//....2....cvWaitKey(33); 33 ms delay, does nothing at all
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); 
//....3....cvWaitKey(33); 33 ms delay, does nothing at all
if(!frame) return -5;

//create a blank image and assigned to 'imgTracking' which has the same size of original video
imgTracking=cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame),IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
//covert the image, 'imgTracking' to black
cvZero(imgTracking);

cvNamedWindow("Video");     
cvNamedWindow("Ball");

//iterate through each frames of the video     
while(true){

    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);           
    if(!frame) break;
    frame=cvCloneImage(frame); 

    //smooth the original image using Gaussian kernel
    cvSmooth(frame, frame, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3); 

    IplImage* imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3); 
    //Change the color format from BGR to HSV
    cvCvtColor(frame, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV); 
    IplImage* imgThresh = GetThresholdedImage(imgHSV);

    //smooth the binary image using Gaussian kernel
    cvSmooth(imgThresh, imgThresh, CV_GAUSSIAN,3,3);

    //track the possition of the ball
    trackObject(imgThresh);

    // Add the tracking image and the frame
    cvAdd(frame, imgTracking, frame);

    cvShowImage("Ball", imgThresh);           
    cvShowImage("Video", frame);

    //Clean up used images
    cvReleaseImage(&imgHSV);
    cvReleaseImage(&imgThresh);            
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);

    //Wait 10mS
    int c = cvWaitKey(33);
    //If 'ESC' is pressed, break the loop
    if((char)c==27 ) break;      
}

cvDestroyAllWindows() ;
cvReleaseImage(&imgTracking);
cvReleaseCapture(&capture);     

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//....2....cvWaitKey(33); 33 ms delay, does nothing at all
```

This is the expected behavior since it waits 33 msec if there is an open window. If you want those lines to work you should open a window before that line.

And try running line `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);` twice, for some reason it may not capture image in the first, just try it.

Comment: checked that, nothing happens, again setting breakpoint causes code to work.

Comment: i can not express my feelings, but after first comment i see your edit and test it, two times `frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);` works

Comment: And one advice, please stop using outdated C-API and start using C++ API.